# Are questions about constructed scripts for natural languages on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

I want to ask a question about the [Deseret Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deseret_alphabet), a constructed script created in the mid-1800's by the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints as a proposed replacement for the Roman script in English. There was very little popular uptake and the project was canceled, but the script as it exists is well-documented and remains usable in theory. Is such a constructed *script*, intended by its creators to be used only with existing natural languages, on-topic? We have the tag [writing-systems](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-systems), but most of the questions appear to be about constructed scripts *associated with corresponding constructed languages* (e.g. Klingon script used to write Klingon).

Comment: Yep, we already have some of those questions, such as [mine on Wakandan](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/q/600/113).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think constructed alphabets for natural languages are OK here. There is no other site on the SE network where such questions are appreciated (linguistics says meh, English language and usage will kick you out, it is not about puzzling nor science fiction) and I see the common aspects to constructed languages as a plus here.